# Add AppPart in subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, app-part

Now,I working project using  SharePoint 2013. Now I'm having problems following: In visual  studio 2013, i create AppPart and deploy it to  SharePoint site. At  SharePoint site collection I create subsite, when edit subsite and add appPart then I don't look it
Pls help me Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppPart will be available to that site only which you have given while deploying the AppPart from Visual Studio. It will not be available on Subsite of that site.

So if you want that your AppPart should available to subsite then please re-deploy the AppPart with the url of your subsite using Visual Studio. So you must install the app on each individual site where it is needed

For more information you can read [Tenancies and deployment scopes for SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179896.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks. I think when apppart available in sitecollection then it available on subsite